# Image oriention issue capture from camera

Tags: android

I was facing a problem image capture from camera it was showing image in landscape even though i capture that image in portrait then i found code online. But i think there is some problem with this code it sometimes didn't work (show image in landscape). So what's wrong there

```
private void adjustImageOrientation() 
    {
        ExifInterface exif;
        int rotate = 0;

        try 
        {
                exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
                int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                switch (exifOrientation) 
                {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                }


            if (rotate != 0) 
            {
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
                try
                {
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);       
                }
                catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, w/2, h/2, mtx, false); 

                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

      //  return image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }
```

Comment: Are you always taking your picture in portrait? What device are you testing your code?

Comment: pictures which i am using for testing are captured in portrait mode. i am testing it on galaxy s4

Comment: What are you doing with the resulting bitmap after you capture it? Do you show it in an ImageView?

Comment: Did you checked if your rotate value takes any value different from 0?